# Get parameter from EXECUTE statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create procedures with dynamic query like this

```
set @x = @query + CAST(@year AS varchar(10)) + ' and ' + @attribute + @operator +''''+ @value+''''
execute (@x)
```

Now I want to get value from execute statement but

```
select * from execute(@x)
```

does not work! Please help me

Comment: I think `execute (@x)` is alone enough if dynamic query is correct

Comment: of course it worked , but i dont want this result i want convert result to  somethings i need . example execute (@x) return geometry type and want convert it to nvarchar() by STAstext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a variable you will use to get the value from the dynamic query and use `executesql` to execute your query.

Something like:

```
declare @x int 
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT @x = SomeColumn FROM SomeTable' 
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@x int out', @x out
select @x
```

Comment: The equivalent would be a table variable but you cannot modify it in dynamic SQL, I think.

Comment: I had a question, how can i using cursor with sp_executesql? or    different ways can execute string sql to using cursor .Sorry my bad english